# Where can I find precompiled bootloader files (initramfs-linux.img)?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, compiling, download

I need the boot files (initramfs-linux.img and vmlinuz-linux) from Arch 4.20-1 to fix a system. Is there a standard place where these can be found, or can they only be custom built?

When I look in [the git archive for Arch](https://git.archlinux.org/linux.git/?h=v4.20-arch1) it apparently only has the files to build these files. For example, there is a gen_initramfs_list.sh script that packs the initramfs.

In my case I am working from a different windows machine than the system that needs to be fixed, so it would be a lot easier if I could download a precompiled version and move it to the broken system, rather than have to create an environment to build it.

Comment: Must we have to rebuild initramfs on every system to make it work?

Comment: Why not boot a Arch Linux on a USB stick, connect network, mount, chroot and reinstall kernel with Pacman?

Comment: @nwildner Because copying 2 files would be easier.

Comment: Wouldn't than be better if you download the `linux` package and then unpack it? - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/offline_installation_of_packages - If your Kernel package is corrupted, that will fix it

Comment: @nwildner Nothing is wrong with the package. The problem is that the version of the initramfs on ESP does not match the installed version. So I need to manually update the initramfs on the ESP partition so that it matches the version of Arch I have installed on the root partition.

Comment: If it is only a matter of initcpio, you just need to do the arch chroot thing, and run `mkinitcpio -p linux`. This way you will have a brand new generated initcpio and you can fix the rest of the system while it's bootable :)

Answer (score 0):

I searched around and could not find any repository with pre-compiled boot files for Arch.

In my case I was able to fix the system anyway because the updated boot files were in the (ext4) /boot directory. So the problem was just to copy those files to the (unmounted) EFI directory containing the "real" boot files on the VFAT partition. So, I mounted the EFI partition and copied the files and the system booted normally after that.